# How do you get through the Toxic Tanks instead of getting Ace's Sewer Shafts Key?

Tags: dex

How do you get through the Toxic Tanks instead of getting Ace's Sewer Shafts Key?

I assume you make the jump from [this part](https://youtu.be/udqZBUoaMsg?t=288) of a Chemical Plant walkthrough, but that person has the Artificial Limbs for High Jump, letting them climb up.

I don't have that and I've tried to climb up there a lot, so I think I can't? I just have to do Ace's quest or Convince him?

Or am I just missing something about how to jump?

But [the Wiki](https://dex-rpg.fandom.com/wiki/A_Bridge_Too_Close) mentions a Toxic Tanks path is possible:

> NOTE: Technically, there is a 4th option of going the long way through the "Toxic Tanks" to reach Fixer's Hope. Because of the poisonous vapour and drip hazards, however, this option is NOT recommended at such an early point in the game.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You jump up, and instead of hitting E or anything, just get close to the ledge and hold Up, then you automatically climb up.

It's the second bit of the movement tutorial:

[image: Ledge Grab Movement Tutorial]